# How to add a background color to Kinetic JS stage or layer?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have a Kinetic JS stage and a layer

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width    : STAGE_WIDTH,
    height   : STAGE_HEIGHT
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

I've set the page color to be #bbb.

```
body {
        background: #bbb;
    }
```

I'd like to set the canvas color to be white. But I can't seem to find a method or a way to add a background color to the stage itself or the layer that I add all the object on.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the background color of your container element through CSS. That's essentially the same as setting the background color of the stage. If you want a background at the layer level, you'll need to add a filled rectangle or similar, as previously mentioned.

Comment: +1 This is the recommended approach because canvas isn't required at the container DOM level

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can access the content DOM element, which is created by KineticJS and nested directly inside the container.  This content node contains all of the layer canvases.  You can access this element like this - var contentDiv = stage.getContent()

Comment: I tried setting the background in CSS with the background and background-color properties, but it didn't make a difference. My canvas had the same color specified for the <body> in CSS.

Comment: Can you share a sample to illustrate how the background isn't working for you? Here's a simple jsfiddle showing how to address the background of the page, the container div, and the sub-container that kinetic creates for you. http://jsfiddle.net/EGbLx/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I wanted to add a "background". I added a rectagle with the 100% height and width, with this code:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: stageDimensions.width, //full width
            height: stageDimensions.height, //full height
            fill: 'white', //background color
        });
layer.add(rect);
```

Since I wanted to be able to remove the "background", this is how I manage to solve my problem.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background color with JavaScript...

```
document.getElementById('container').style.background = '#fff';
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API method to add a background color.

Instead add a colored rectangle that covers the layer.

Of course, add the background rectangle before all other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you can use the `get` properties of the stage, and fill a full rectangle, adding it to the layer before anything else. Sample code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'canvas-container',
  width: 900,
  height: 450
});

// create background
var stageBg = new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: stage.getWidth(),
  height: stage.getHeight(),
  fill: "rgb(40,40,40)"
});

layer.add(stageBg);
stage.add(layer);
```